# Wow slider with react.js is not working

Tags: reactjs, fullpage.js, wowslider

I have created a page with fullpage.js and in one of the sections I've integrated wow slider. Same thing is working perfectly in html page but not when integrated in react.js. Getting following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>       at N

Script for wow slider

```
function ws_glass_parallax(d,l,m){var f=jQuery;var i=f(this);var j=d.parallax||0.25;var k=f("<div>").css({position:"absolute",display:"none",top:0,left:0,width:"100%",height:"100%",overflow:"hidden"}).addClass("ws_effect ws_glass_parallax").appendTo(m);var h=!d.noCanvas&&!window.opera&&!!document.createElement("canvas").getContext;if(h){try{document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,1,1)}catch(q){h=0}}function t(e){return Math.round(e*1000)/1000}var u=f("<div>").css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,overflow:"hidden",width:"100%",height:"100%",transform:"translate3d(0,0,0)",zIndex:1}).appendTo(k);var s=u.clone().appendTo(k);var r=u.clone().css({width:"20%"}).appendTo(k);var c;var p=u.clone().appendTo(k).css({zIndex:0});this.go=function(C,A,x){var e=f(l.get(A));e={position:"absolute",width:e.width(),height:e.height(),marginTop:e.css("marginTop"),marginLeft:e.css("marginLeft")};x=x?1:-1;var E=f(l.get(A)).clone().css(e).appendTo(u);var z=f(l.get(C)).clone().css(e).appendTo(s);var v=f(l.get(C)).clone().css(e).appendTo(r);if(x==-1){r.css({left:"auto",right:0});v.css({left:"auto",right:0})}else{r.css({left:0,right:"auto"});v.css({left:0,right:"auto"})}var D=(m.width()||d.width)*1.3;var B=m.height()||d.height;var y;if(h){if(!c){c=f("<canvas>").css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0}).attr({width:e.width,height:e.height}).appendTo(p)}c.css(e).attr({width:e.width,height:e.height});y=o(f(l.get(C)),e,10,c.get(0))}if(!h||!y){h=0}wowAnimate(function(G){G=f.easing.swing(G);var L=t(x*G*D),F=t(x*(-D+G*D-(1-G)*D*0.2)),J=t(x*(-D*1.4+G*(D*1.4+D/1.3))),w=t(-x*D*j*G),H=t(x*D*j*(1-G)),I=t(-x*D*(j+0.2)*G),K=t(x*(-D*0.2+G*D*0.4));if(d.support.transform){u.css("transform","translate3d("+L+"px,0,0)");E.css("transform","translate3d("+w+"px,0,0)");s.css("transform","translate3d("+F+"px,0,0)");z.css("transform","translate3d("+H+"px,0,0)");r.css("transform","translate3d("+J+"px,0,0)");v.css("transform","scale(1.6) translate3d("+I+"px,0,0)");p.css("transform","translate3d("+K+"px,0,0)")}else{u.css("left",L);E.css("margin-left",w);s.css("left",F);z.css("margin-left",H);r.css("left",J);v.css("margin-left",I);p.css("left",K)}},0,1,d.duration,function(){k.hide();E.remove();z.remove();v.remove();i.trigger("effectEnd")})};function o(C,A,B,v){var F=(parseInt(C.parent().css("z-index"))||0)+1;if(h){var I=v.getContext("2d");I.drawImage(C.get(0),0,0,A.width,A.height);if(!a(I,0,0,v.width,v.height,B)){return 0}return f(v)}var J=f("<div></div>").css({position:"absolute","z-index":F,left:0,top:0}).css(A).appendTo(v);var H=(Math.sqrt(5)+1)/2;var w=1-H/2;for(var z=0;w*z<B;z++){var D=Math.PI*H*z;var e=(w*z+1);var G=e*Math.cos(D);var E=e*Math.sin(D);f(document.createElement("img")).attr("src",C.attr("src")).css({opacity:1/(z/1.8+1),position:"absolute","z-index":F,left:Math.round(G)+"px",top:Math.round(E)+"px",width:"100%",height:"100%"}).appendTo(J)}return J}var g=[512,512,456,512,328,456,335,512,405,328,271,456,388,335,292,512,454,405,364,328,298,271,496,456,420,388,360,335,312,292,273,512,482,454,428,405,383,364,345,328,312,298,284,271,259,496,475,456,437,420,404,388,374,360,347,335,323,312,302,292,282,273,265,512,497,482,468,454,441,428,417,405,394,383,373,364,354,345,337,328,320,312,305,298,291,284,278,271,265,259,507,496,485,475,465,456,446,437,428,420,412,404,396,388,381,374,367,360,354,347,341,335,329,323,318,312,307,302,297,292,287,282,278,273,269,265,261,512,505,497,489,482,475,468,461,454,447,441,435,428,422,417,411,405,399,394,389,383,378,373,368,364,359,354,350,345,341,337,332,328,324,320,316,312,309,305,301,298,294,291,287,284,281,278,274,271,268,265,262,259,257,507,501,496,491,485,480,475,470,465,460,456,451,446,442,437,433,428,424,420,416,412,408,404,400,396,392,388,385,381,377,374,370,367,363,360,357,354,350,347,344,341,338,335,332,329,326,323,320,318,315,312,310,307,304,302,299,297,294,292,289,287,285,282,280,278,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259];var n=[9,11,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24];function a(am,U,S,v,w,ad){if(isNaN(ad)||ad<1){return}ad|=0;var ah;try{ah=am.getImageData(U,S,v,w)}catch(al){console.log("error:unable to access image data: "+al);return false}var C=ah.data;var ab,aa,aj,ag,J,M,G,A,B,R,H,T,P,X,ac,K,F,L,N,W;var ak=ad+ad+1;var Y=v<<2;var I=v-1;var af=w-1;var E=ad+1;var ae=E*(E+1)/2;var V=new b();var Q=V;for(aj=1;aj<ak;aj++){Q=Q.next=new b();if(aj==E){var D=Q}}Q.next=V;var ai=null;var Z=null;G=M=0;var O=g[ad];var z=n[ad];for(aa=0;aa<w;aa++){X=ac=K=A=B=R=0;H=E*(F=C[M]);T=E*(L=C[M+1]);P=E*(N=C[M+2]);A+=ae*F;B+=ae*L;R+=ae*N;Q=V;for(aj=0;aj<E;aj++){Q.r=F;Q.g=L;Q.b=N;Q=Q.next}for(aj=1;aj<E;aj++){ag=M+((I<aj?I:aj)<<2);A+=(Q.r=(F=C[ag]))*(W=E-aj);B+=(Q.g=(L=C[ag+1]))*W;R+=(Q.b=(N=C[ag+2]))*W;X+=F;ac+=L;K+=N;Q=Q.next}ai=V;Z=D;for(ab=0;ab<v;ab++){C[M]=(A*O)>>z;C[M+1]=(B*O)>>z;C[M+2]=(R*O)>>z;A-=H;B-=T;R-=P;H-=ai.r;T-=ai.g;P-=ai.b;ag=(G+((ag=ab+ad+1)<I?ag:I))<<2;X+=(ai.r=C[ag]);ac+=(ai.g=C[ag+1]);K+=(ai.b=C[ag+2]);A+=X;B+=ac;R+=K;ai=ai.next;H+=(F=Z.r);T+=(L=Z.g);P+=(N=Z.b);X-=F;ac-=L;K-=N;Z=Z.next;M+=4}G+=v}for(ab=0;ab<v;ab++){ac=K=X=B=R=A=0;M=ab<<2;H=E*(F=C[M]);T=E*(L=C[M+1]);P=E*(N=C[M+2]);A+=ae*F;B+=ae*L;R+=ae*N;Q=V;for(aj=0;aj<E;aj++){Q.r=F;Q.g=L;Q.b=N;Q=Q.next}J=v;for(aj=1;aj<=ad;aj++){M=(J+ab)<<2;A+=(Q.r=(F=C[M]))*(W=E-aj);B+=(Q.g=(L=C[M+1]))*W;R+=(Q.b=(N=C[M+2]))*W;X+=F;ac+=L;K+=N;Q=Q.next;if(aj<af){J+=v}}M=ab;ai=V;Z=D;for(aa=0;aa<w;aa++){ag=M<<2;C[ag]=(A*O)>>z;C[ag+1]=(B*O)>>z;C[ag+2]=(R*O)>>z;A-=H;B-=T;R-=P;H-=ai.r;T-=ai.g;P-=ai.b;ag=(ab+(((ag=aa+E)<af?ag:af)*v))<<2;A+=(X+=(ai.r=C[ag]));B+=(ac+=(ai.g=C[ag+1]));R+=(K+=(ai.b=C[ag+2]));ai=ai.next;H+=(F=Z.r);T+=(L=Z.g);P+=(N=Z.b);X-=F;ac-=L;K-=N;Z=Z.next;M+=v}}am.putImageData(ah,U,S);return true}function b(){this.r=0;this.g=0;this.b=0;this.a=0;this.next=null}};

jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({effect:"glass_parallax",prev:"",next:"",duration:20*100,delay:20*100,width:640,height:360,autoPlay:false,autoPlayVideo:false,playPause:false,stopOnHover:false,loop:false,bullets:1,caption:true,captionEffect:"traces",controls:false,controlsThumb:false,responsive:2,fullScreen:false,gestures:2,onBeforeStep:0,images:0});
```

Created app using create-react-app
App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

          <ul id="menu">
              <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">firstPage</a></li>
              <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">secondPage</a></li>
              <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">3rdPage</a></li>
              <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">4thpage</a></li>
              <li data-menuanchor="5thpage"><a href="#5thpage">5thpage</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="fullpage">
              <div className="section " id="section0">
                  <div className="intro">
                      <p>Your Virtual Assistant</p>
                      <p>Free your time for the things that matter to you.</p>


                      <p>be part of the first release, <br/> duw out shortly</p>

                      <a href="#">Sign up today</a>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="section" id="section1">
                  <div className="intro">
                      <h1>No limitations!</h1>
                      <p>Content is a priority. Even if it is so large :)</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="section" id="section2">

                  <div id="wowslider-container1">
                      <div className="ws_images"><ul>
                          <li><img src="images/background_1.jpg" alt="Background_1" title="Background_1" id="wows1_0"/></li>
                          <li><img src="images/sample_1.jpg" alt="Sample_1" title="Sample_1" id="wows1_1"/></li>
                          <li><a href="http://wowslider.net"><img src="images/sample_2.jpg" alt="javascript carousel" title="Sample_2" id="wows1_2"/></a></li>
                          <li><img src="images/sample_3.jpg" alt="Sample_3" title="Sample_3" id="wows1_3"/></li>
                      </ul></div>
                      <div className="ws_bullets"><div>
                          <a href="" title="Background_1"><span>1</span></a>
                          <a href="" title="Sample_1"><span>2</span></a>
                          <a href="" title="Sample_2"><span>3</span></a>
                          <a href="" title="Sample_3"><span>4</span></a>
                      </div></div><div className="ws_script" ><a href="http://wowslider.net">css image gallery</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.8m</div>
                      <div className="ws_shadow"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="section" id="section3">
                  <div className="intro">
                      <h1>No limitations!</h1>
                      <p>Content is a priority. Even if it is so large :)</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="section" id="section4">
                  <div className="intro">
                      <h1>No limitations!</h1>
                      <p>Content is a priority. Even if it is so large :)</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.html page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.1/jquery.fullPage.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/examples.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolloverflow.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                // anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage'],
                sectionsColor: ['#4A6FB1', '#939FAA', '#323539','#4A6FB1','#939FAA'],
                // scrollOverflow: true
                // sectionsColor: ['', '#939FAA', '#fff','#fff','','#fff','',''],
                anchors:
                    ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage','6thpage','7thpage','8thpage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                css3: true,
                scrollingSpeed: 1000,
                scrollOverflow: true,
                fixedElements: '10',
                // paddingTop: '3em',
                lockAnchors: true,
                // scrollBar:true,
                onLeave: function(){

                }
            });
        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use jQuery with ReactJS.

Comment: yeah... I know it's not recommended but client wants same animation and it's available in wow slider only. My main concern is it works in plain HTML but doesn't in react.js

Comment: Where you locate the script for wow slider ?

Comment: @Carr In script.js file which I've included on index.html page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the revision as little as possible, try to prefix the `window` to external library (use as global variable)

`jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider(...)`

to

`window.jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider(...)`

Here is [explanation on CRA doc](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables).

The part I could not understand is that why you need the function

```
function ws_glass_parallax(d,l,m){...}
```

in your script.js.

But I cannot make sure it would work as expected cause that I think this is not the anticipated way to develop in react.

My suggestion, including the `fullpage` utilization you deployed in **index.html** should just move to `componentDidMount()` which could roughly seem as the same place as `$(document).ready(function() {})`

so the whole picture should be:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    window.JQuery(this.refs.fullpageEle).fullpage({...});
    window.JQuery(this.refs.wow).wowSlider({...});
}  
render() {
      return (
          <div className="App">
              <ul id="menu"> ... </ul>
              <div id="fullpage" ref="fullpage" >
                  <div className="section" id="section0"> ... </div>
                  <div className="section" id="section1"> ... </div>
                  <div className="section" id="section2">
                      <div id="wowslider-container1" ref="wow">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="section" id="section3"> ... </div>
                  <div className="section" id="section4"> ... </div>
              </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
export default App;
```

Something may be new to you is `ref` which I add in your target element and we  refer the element by it in `componenetDidMount()`, here is the description on official [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

And leave **index.html** only including external source but not JS code.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried your solution. I have kept all the things same as you explained. Just for demo I've added scripts like this. What bothers me is, fullpgae + wowslider with same scripts works fine in HTML but doesn't in react.

Comment: @vartika, sorry for that, but not sure what "added script like this" means? Or maybe try to re-produce your problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/new, the framework using here is CRA too.
And you could show what can work and what cannot.